# How to have domain for Azure VM

Tags: azure, ssl, dns, certificate, virtual-machine

I did a research a few days about this. But still do not find any solution yet.

I have vm that host a website. The IP address for this website able to access from outside. But now i want to have custom domain for this vm.

Anyone know where I should refer to? Please share any link etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a A DNS record with your domain name registar, or use Azure DNS (you would need to delegate your domain to Azure DNS), or use Azure [built-in DNS for your VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn). If you dont have a domain - you need to buy it first.

https://serverfault.com/questions/143411/godaddy-linking-domain-name-to-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

After you deployed an Azure VM, you also could configure an FQDN for this VM so that you can access the VM via Azure Provided DNS resolution which is mapped to the public IP address of Azure VM. Read how to create a [FQDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn). If so, you could directly access the VM via this FQDN.

Otherwise, you need to purchase a domain then use a `CNAME` to redirect your custom domain like `www.example.com` to this FQDN or use a `A` record mapping to the public IP address in your domain provider.

Comment: I already purchase a domain. But that domain provider need nameserver1 and nameserver2. Where can i get this nameserver in VM?

Comment: Do you want to host that DNS zone in Azure? If you just create DNS records, you do not need to do that. You just need to create `A` or `CNAME` record, no need to modify the `NS` record in the DNS zone.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I still couldn't make it. The situation is i already create key vault & ssl certificate in Azure. I also done with import .pfx in that VM (refer to this blog - http://blog.powerbiz.net.au/server-2012/importing-a-pfx-certificate-into-windows-server-2012/)

But still my url (http://redeem.plusmiles.com.my) will unable to access via https

Comment: You need bind cert with port 443 in IIS in Azure VM, try `New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -Protocol https -Port 443`
`Get-ChildItem cert:\localmachine\My | New-Item -Path IIS:\SslBindings\!443` refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-secure-web-server